# Creating a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays, that I want to put into 1 multidimensional array

```
$array_result = array();
Array1 = a,b,c,d
Array2 = 1,2,3,4
```

The result that I want to get is

```
$array_result = [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => 2

    )  etc...
```

I can't work out how to do this. Then length of Array1 and Array2 varies as it is dynamic data.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3,4);
$arr2 = array('a','b','c','d');
$arr3 = array();
for($i = 0;$i< count($arr1);$i++) {
    $arr = array();
    $arr[] = $arr2[$i];
    $arr[] = $arr1[$i];
    array_push($arr3,$arr);
}
```

## Output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => 1
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => 2
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => 3
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => d
        [1] => 4
    )
)
```

## Codepad Demo

Comment: You use `$arr[]`, yet you have the overhead of calling a function with `array_push()` for the exact same thing. Also, what will happen if both arrays aren't the same size, for example if `count( $arr1) > count( $arr2)`? This [will generate tons of undefined offset notices](http://viper-7.com/UfrHBC).

Comment: My arrays are always the same size. Thanks Yogesh!

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function. It should do what you want to do.

```
$array_result=array_merge($array1, $array2, ...);
```